# Flask : ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, flask

I am a Newbee in Python, Flask and API, and trying to learn it with my own project.

The API I am querying requires Basic Authentication.
Created a `login.html` and `dashboard.html` as templates of Flask.
Created a module `myclasses.py`
and the `reporter.py` which is the main module for Flask Views and other code.

`login.html` request user for IP, Username and Password which is captured in `(/)` view, and then forwarded to the Function defined in `MyClasses.py` using "call_api" to form the API and the function returns the Data.

Now I don't know and not sure how to proceed with forwarding the received data as json to `(/dashboard)` view for parsing and displaying in Dashboard template page.

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, request, json
    from MyClasses import call_api

    app = Flask(__name__)

    data = "no data"
    status_code = 0

    @app.route('/dashboard')
        def dashboard():
            return render_template('dashboard.html', data=data, status_code=status_code)


    @app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
        def login():
        if request.method == "POST":
            creds = {'ipaddr': request.form['inip'],
            'username': request.form['inusername'],
            'password': request.form['inpassword'],
            'entity': 'info'
            }
        request_dump = call_api(creds['ipaddr'], creds['username'], creds['password'], creds['entity'])
            if request_dump[1] == 200:
                global data
                global status_code
                    data = (json.dumps(request_dump[0], indent=2))
                    status_code = request_dump[1]
                    return redirect(url_for('dashboard')), status_code, data
            else:
                return render_template('login.html')
        else:
        return render_template('login.html')
```

I am getting error, what does this means?

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

If I remove status_code, data, it works fine.

```
return redirect(url_for('dashboard')), status_code, data
```

for sure, I am not doing it the right way in many areas of this code.
Also, If you guys tell me on how to debug the code when flask is involved, I tried using breakpoints in PyCharm but code does not stops when I browse the templates.

Appreciate you help and Thank you for the time.

Comment: Works fine in the sense, the user is forwarded to dashboard page. of course there is no content on it which i want to parse and display in dashboard view.

Comment: Does `redirect(url_for('dashboard') , code=status_code, data)` work? this is the whole function specification: `flask.redirect(location, code=302, Response=None)`

Comment: As you've figured it out yourself, you cannot return status_code, data with it. But, I don't understand why the data and status_code aren't accessed otherwise. Try printing the values of these variables before the return statement in both `def login()` and `def dashboard()`

Comment: @Remember1312 If I put the var in redirect, it does not work as well as the data is visible in URL.

Comment: @MoosaSaadat I can get the print output only in def login() and not inside def dashboard()

Comment: @Wasim just to get us both on the same page, you'll get print output inside `dashboard()` when you are redirected to `/dashboard`. You've tried it this way? Also, please share runnable code with relevant files so that we can test on it.

Comment: @MoosaSaadat I am putting a subnet of login() and dashboard() here


login func as below: (added comment)
```
            data = (json.dumps(request_dump[0], indent=2))
            status_code = request_dump[1]
            # print(f':::{status_code}{data}')  # shows in console
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard')), status_code, data
        else:
```

dashboard func as below: (added comment)
```
@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    print(f':::{status_code}{data}') # No output
    return render_template('dashboard.html', data=data, status=status_code)
```

Comment: :-( can't mark the code as ``` code ``` in comments

Comment: I was trying to say that `print(f':::{status_code}{data}') # No output` should return some value. It will print the values when you go to the url `/dashboard`. And, it will be really helpful if you can set up a reproducable problem in `repl.it`. Also, you can use single backticks ` instead of triple ``` for inline code formatting (in comments)

Comment: Hello @MoosaSaadat, The Print inside `(/dashboard)` seems to be giving result now, also because the object type of `data` was dictionary `{dictionary:[list,{dictionary:}]}` thats why sending it through return to Flask template page was giving the error in question. I have to adjust the Flask template code with some `{% for %}` to show the results.

Answer (score 0):

reconstructing the dictionary to a customized (data that I need) within the `dashboard()` as well as correcting the Flask template with `{% for loop %}` resolved the issue.

Flask Template snippet below:

```
    <table class="containertbl">
  <tbody>
  {% for key,value in ddo.items() %}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{ key }}</th>
      <td>{{ value }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```